# How to remove sass_functions.scss in PhpStorm/WebStorm?

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm

How can I remove the autocompletion sass_functions.scss in PhpStorm/WebStorm

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Those are Sass standard functions. Why do you want to remove them? If it can be removed .. then IDE will not be offering them for you at all (and quite possibly will not be able to recognize them as well).

Comment: Maybe you just need the order of the proposed elements to be changed: show actual properties first and only then list Sass functions? It was fixed long time ago (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-6452) but looks like it came back. if so -- feel free to create new ticket at Issue Tracker (and post link to it back here)

Comment: @LazyOne Yes, I need have css properties on first positions. For example transform: ...

Comment: Looks like it was already reported by one of the devs/support team -- please follow this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30267

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in IntelliJ 2017.3.2 (173.4261). You can see the fixed ticket at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-30267.